# Css3 Transitions understanding

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to create a hover over my navbar links like the ones in this example
      http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39513/index.html

I don’t necessarily want the answer but more of what resources or guides I need to look out to understand what is happening. From what I read so far CSS3 has transitions which would control this function?

I would like to learn how it works, especially with the example i want to achieve.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting example, Richlewis. On the page you shown us the transition is used on each `li` element in the menu. In their style sheet you can find these lines:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

This basically means "use transitions on all properties of this li element". Though, in this example, the most important is the `background-position` property. It is used to scroll the background when you hover over this element.

And the background pattern (which can be found here: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39513/images/nav_li.png) is just a 1px wide green image with two transparent gaps.

If you'd like to read more about transitions in CSS3, I've found a great article here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: You might want to look up vendor prefixes as well.

Comment: Thx, SpaceBeers. I've added them to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the information, so the vendor prefixes are added to the li in the stylesheet, in my case my li are in a div called nav, so .nav > li get the prefixes?

Comment: vendor prefixes are those -webkit-, -moz-, -o-, etc. prefixes for vendor-specific properties. You can read more about them here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

Comment: Thanks again @zeroos, got it all working and i understand a little more about how transitions work